# Is a 996 work schedule legal in the US?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, hours

The company I work for insinuated that they were going to require a 996 (9am-9pm, 6 days a week) work schedule. We'd probably be paid for all the hours worked. I'm curious if requiring that schedule violates any US labor laws?

Comment: This belongs to https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What about this wouldn't be legal?

Comment: While I agree with newguy, I suspect you haven't given enough information even for Law SE. Is that exempt or non-exempt? What kind of a break schedule are they talking about? Is this for a specific project with a well defined end point? How is this expected to affect your pay?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's legal or not, it sounds like a great way for your company to get all their employees to produce low quality work due to exhaustion before they inevitably quit.

Comment: The beautiful thing is... it doesn't matter.  I mean, either way, do you actually want to work there?

Comment: @kevin no way, iwas just curious because it's suited up controversy in China where they came up with the idea because it violates their labor laws.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you're over 16, the only limit in the USA is that the employer must pay you for all worked hours, and must pay overtime when you work over 40. However, state law may have lower limits.

https://webapps.dol.gov/elaws/whd/flsa/screen6.asp

https://www.dol.gov/whd/state/rest.htm